# Load ValidationSummary using ajax

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

How to load ValidationSummary using ajax? I was trying to use MVC's ready Membership.

Simple question, but I'm stuck.

```
[HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [RecaptchaControlMvc.CaptchaValidator]
    public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model, bool captchaValid, string captchaErrorMessage)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Attempt to register the user
                try
                {
                    if (captchaValid)
                    {
                        WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password);
                        WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password);
                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                    }
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", captchaErrorMessage);
                }
                catch (MembershipCreateUserException e)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(e.StatusCode));
                }

        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary()

<fieldset>
    <legend>Registration Form</legend>
    <ol>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
            <input type="hidden" id ="some" value=""/>
        </li>etc.
```

I don't want to redirect each time on for example, if username exists or etc.

Answer (score 1):

To do this you can return a partial view as html.  The rendered partial will contain the modelstate errors and therefore will display when returned as html.

**Example**

Could can create a class called AjaxResult

```
public class AjaxResult
{
    public string Html { get; set; }
    public bool Success { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your success function from the ajax call you can append the html to the appropriate element. e.g.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://bacon/receive', 
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    error: function () {
    },
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.Success) {
            $('body').append(data.Html);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: +1, but would using a bool for "Success" would just make more sense.

Comment: gave up Html.BeginForm(). used Ajax.BeginForm().